# How to add iPod EQ when playing audio with AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, avplayer, equalizer

I am able to play songs from iPod library using AVPlayer class.
Now what I want to do is to insert equalizer to the audio produced.

Anybody has experienced in doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to play MPMediaItem and adding sound equalizer with AVPlayer. We have to use Audio Unit processing.

Comment: I recommend you to make the equalizer using NVDSP: https://github.com/bartolsthoorn/NVDSP It's really easy.

Comment: @bartolsthoorn how would you play songs from the iPod library with NVDSP. Novocaine does not allow you to play songs from the iPod library. Also can you provide some sample code?

Comment: Fedry can you help me a lil with EQ using Novocaine?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this leveraging a class provided in the Apple Samples:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/avTouch/Listings/Classes_CALevelMeter_h.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: The sample is about displaying level meter. I cannot find anything related to equalizer.