# How to apply iPodEQ effect to single audio input unit on ios

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, core-audio, audiotoolbox, core-media

I Tried to implement a audio player which fetches music from library and can apply EQ settings by the user in the app. After referring the [following links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889857/add-ipod-equalizer-effect-using-avplayer) I came to know that we can implement it using audio units only. I started reading the basics of the core audio framework. I understood how it is working but I failed to connect all dots. I found [Apple sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iPhoneMixerEQGraphTest/Introduction/Intro.html) which contains two input units passed through mixer and set output to output units. As per my understanding I think the ipod EQ effect is applying to second input only.
[image: two inputs passed to mixer and sent output to output unit]
 But in my case I have only one input unit (a song from library) apply EQ settings and set it to output unit. I failed in convert it as per my requirement can anyone help me in implementing this.

Thanks you,