# iOS Swift : How to add equalizer options like High pitch, Reverb, stereo in AVPlayer for Video file

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avaudioengine, equalizer

I am working on an app which uses AVPlayer to play a video file through url it is working fine, but now I want to add Equalizer options like treble, stereo in it. I have gone through many questions in SO but all of them are associated to Audio files i have to change it in Video file. I used AudioEngine and some other methods to do so but it is not working as expected.

Is there any library for presets in iOS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16889857/6630644

Comment: @SPatel i checked the above link but i already tried this and it is associate to audio section. i need to make change in Video

Comment: I believe its same for video